# How do I read line by line in a file using while loop, and in each iteration, grep each line to compare to a string?

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a file called abc.txt with the contents as follows:

```
1: It is a shell script
2: There are few lines in this file
3: I am good with programming in C, but beginner in shell
4: We are going towards end of file
5: END OF FILE
```

I want to read each of the file iteratively, and in each iteration I want to compare the line with "I am good with programming in C, but beginner in shell", and then do some processing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Using a shell loop is unnecessary, as `grep` already iterates over lines:

```
grep '^[0-9]:  I am good with programming in C, but beginner in shell' input.txt
```

If there's a matching line, it will be printed. `[0-9]` defines range of characters that will be matched. We can also extend that to longer numbers `[0-9]*:` (and I think with perl regex `-P` option that could be done as `[0-9]+:`).

If a shell loop is really necessary, we can use `case` statement for pattern matching

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
        *": I am good with programming in C") echo "Matched: $line";;
    esac
done < input.xt
```

Comment: `^[0-9]: ` isn't needed at all either, it seems.

Comment: @MichaelHampton To be fair, yes, in this case not needed at all - user can get away with just `.*I am good with programming in C` or just pick a unique word from that sentence. Or even `grep 'C.*shell'`. There's no and statement in grep, but we could get away with `grep 'shell' | grep 'C'` .  Of course, everything depends on user's input data to construct a proper regex pattern.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy,

See this question, this is exactly what I need. Please help!
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098503/how-do-i-transfer-certain-parts-of-the-file-to-another-file

Answer (score 8):

Try this sample code to help identify and modify to suit your needs:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
set -x 

while read -r linenum line
do
        if [ "$line" = "I am good with programming in C, but beginner in shell" ]
        then
                # Process things here
                echo "same"
        fi
done < "$1"
```

Usage:

- Make executable:

  ```
  chmod +x script.sh
  ```
- Place script in any folder then run script by passing a file to it:

  ```
  ./script.sh /path/to/data.txt
  ```

Info:

- `-r`: Option passed to read command prevents backslash escapes from being interpreted.
- `set -e`: Bash option to stop script on first error.
- `set -x`: Bash option used to debug the scrtip.
- `"$1"`: The file variable passed to the script in this case `data.txt`
- `linenum`: variable that holds the line numbers when bash splits the read lines into two variables while the other is passed in via the `lin` variable.

Comment: @George So you're using `-d" "` to split on whitespace and cut all lines starting from the second one. I'd suggest another way: `while IFS= read -r linenum line`. The shell will perform wordsplitting on the input line and place first item (  line numbers ) into `linenum` variable, but all other things will go into `line` variable. Aside from other things, `case` statement can be used as alternative to `[[` comparison.

Comment: Can I implement this script in #!/bin/sh ?

Comment: @AkshayNandi Yes, but you need to change `[[` to `[` because `[[` is specific to `bash`. See my answer for portable solution

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I tried that it didn't do so on the word splitting.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Oh ? Interesting. What was the output you were getting ? Were you still using `cut` ? Because if you just use the loop I suggested, you can drop `cut` from the script

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Ah, yes, I found the issue - it's because of `IFS=`. It unsets the variable temporarily, which is what is used for word splitting. `IFS` defaults to whitespace,tab,and newline. And it's a habit, but also for a good reason, to unset it - if there's a leading whitespace ( line starts with space )  it would be gone without `IFS=`

Comment: @Sergiykolodyazhnyy I have updated my answer, thanks for the learning opportunity!