# How do I transfer certain parts of the file to another file?

Tags: grep

I have a FILE1

```
NAMES START

Hi, How are you?
Good to see you

start
Aaron
Kyle
Robert
stop

Official use only
Stamps here

start
Riley
Gayle
stop

Bicycles here
United Pawns

start
Alex
Ford
Sergio
stop

NAMES STOP
```

Here's what I wanna do:

If "NAMES START" string is present, transfer the contents each "start" and "stop", to a new FILE2, leaving out the start and stop themselves in the new FILE2.

So FILE2 should look like this:

```
Aaron
Kyle
Robert
Riley
Gayle
Alex
Ford
Sergio
```

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Getting content between named blocks of text

Lets address getting the contents inside `start..stop` block because that's the major task.

`grep` is line-matching tool, hence matching across multiple lines is difficult and `grep` is usually not used for such task, [though it's not impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33418344/3701431). However, best approach in such case is to use `awk` to get patterns between specific lines, and then filter out the `start` and `stop` flags:

```
$ awk '/start/,/stop/' input.txt | grep -v 'start\|stop'
Aaron
Kyle
Robert
Riley
Gayle
Alex
Ford
Sergio
```

If we want to get rid of pipeline, we can do:

```
# {print} is actually unnecessary, as default for awk is to print if
# expression evaluates to true, so it's enough to have
# awk '/start/{flag=1;next};/stop/{flag=0};flag' input.txt
$ awk '/start/{flag=1;next};/stop/{flag=0};flag == 1 {print}' input.txt
Aaron
Kyle
Robert
Riley
Gayle
Alex
Ford
Sergio
```

There's of course [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2686147/3701431), such as `sed` or `perl`. As for `grep`, it's often suggested to use `grep -Pzo` flags, however probably due to multiple occurrences of `start..block` it doesn't work properly ( only one match returned):

```
$ grep -zPo --color 'start\n(.*\n.*)\nstop' input.txt
start
Riley
Gayle
stop
```

---

For the sake of simplicity (though arguably `awk` example is the simplest) and to avoid dealing with regex patterns, we can also resort to basic scripting:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

printline=0
while IFS= read -r line; do

    # set flag for printing or not printing
    case $line in 
        "start") printline=1; continue;;
        "stop")  printline=0; continue;;
    esac

    # check the flag
    if [ "$printline" -eq 1  ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
    fi

# first positional parameter is the file we read
done < "$1"
```

And here's how the script works:

```
$ chmod +x readblocks.sh
$ ./readblocks.sh input.txt
Aaron
Kyle
Robert
Riley
Gayle
Alex
Ford
Sergio
```

---

#### Checking for NAMES START and transfering

> If "NAMES START" string is present, transfer the contents each "start" and "stop", to a new FILE2, leaving out the start and stop themselves in the new FILE2.

Well, that's just `grep 'NAMES START' input.txt`. So we can check for that via

```
if grep -q 'NAMES START' input.txt; then
    # whatever method you like goes here
fi
```

Looking at your example, `NAMES START` is the first line of the file. So we can also check for that  - check first line as we read the file, instead of opening the file inside `if` statement suggested above.

Transferring the contents to FILE2 - that's just adding `> FILE2.txt` to the original command or script you use.

With these suggestions, `awk` command becomes:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 && $0 != "NAMES START"{exit};/start/{flag=1;next};/stop/{flag=0};flag' input.txt > FILE2.txt
```

And the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

printline=0
linecounter=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    linecounter=$((linecounter+1))

    case "$line" in
        "NAMES START") continue;;
         *) exit 1;
    esac


    # set flag for printing or not printing
    case $line in 
        "start") printline=1; continue;;
        "stop")  printline=0; continue;;
    esac

    # check the flag
    if [ "$printline" -eq 1  ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
    fi

# first positional parameter is the file we read
done < "$1" > FILE2.txt
```

Comment: You rock! Thank you for your help. I could solve the issue